# Generalized Eigenvalue Problem using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fortran, eigenvalue

I'm trying to solve a generalized eigenvalue problem. I have two matrices H and S such that:

```
HX=λSX
```

I need to find the eigenvalues λ. The matrices H and S are real, asymmetric, contains positive and negative decimal numbers and (can be) singular. I tried this on MATLAB by using the command ***eig(H,S)***, but the problem is that I am obtaining real and complex eigenvalues, while in the research paper that I am following the authors have got only real eigenvalues.

After reading about this problem I have got to know that for such matrices, softwares like MATLAB and many other use the QZ Algorithm to solve generalized eigenavalue problem. I am seeking answers to the following questions:

1. Is there any criteria to determine whether the given matrices will have complex eigenvalues or not? and that the result obtained from MATLAB is correct or not? (though the values don't agree with research paper).
2. In the research paper the authors have used RGG subroutine which is a part of Fortran library EISPACK. I went through its documentation and got to know that it also uses the QZ algorithm. So my question is can MATLAB and Fortran give different answers to the same problem even when both of them are using the same algorithm?

Here are the matrices:

```
H=[0,0,0,0,192,1917.04064,10332.51505,40092.51227,125681.1486,338350.2206,811892.8294,1779728.921,3625982.355,6953387.916,12670976.81,22100000,37132930.27,60353006.25,95276316.19,146559937.4,220274060.5,324208411.9,468219308,664618721.8;
0,0,0,0,192,1893.475124,10051.90014,38308.22391,117609.6433,309187.9535,722364.2569,1537115.973,3030677.025,5606681.841,9824567.083,16426180.74,26355891.41,40770017.02,61031174.08,88683247.04,125403139.6,172926323.5,232944447.3,306974887;
0,0,0,0,192,1846.924351,9507.779872,34923.83828,102685.9158,256815.0258,566753.8301,1130503.089,2072244.588,3531888.862,5644710.273,8510616.36,12154554.65,16481872.51,21234784.98,25958063.51,29983201.26,32440241.94,32304892.86,28485362.66;
0,0,0,0,192,1778.534558,8732.953666,30281.20319,83090.50097,191433.6927,383369.9941,681577.7806,1089000.57,1571702.814,2043718.6,2360415.659,2327150.205,1728131.214,376286.8361,-1820993.208,-4791939.112,-8243585.409,-11638086.16,-14220529.21;
0,0,0,0,192,1689.989727,7773.203992,24831.36406,61515.88289,124689.9821,212051.9399,303583.89,356337.2627,308129.1939,94242.56924,-323226.8121,-920239.2345,-1583058.32,-2104105.201,-2214813.175,-1659107.74,-295993.1841,1796496.926,4254923.427;
0,0,0,0,192,1583.470126,6683.555129,19072.50505,40639.69537,66711.57632,81796.22718,60590.29663,-21861.2573,-171429.7577,-355062.5907,-492927.1661,-475398.2758,-208930.4549,320950.1747,997476.1882,1566265.895,1699768.472,1129529.762,-194208.6509;
0,0,0,0,192,1461.598622,5523.845413,13484.72812,22648.14037,23924.65349,4088.400074,-44523.67789,-110266.4937,-154796.0153,-124116.6074,18352.09343,250026.0416,467393.1673,513093.6957,258167.4211,-292568.7362,-936296.041,-1313188.428,-1070939.742;
0,0,0,0,192,1327.376095,4354.022806,8472.235861,8915.430969,-1775.330646,-26379.77787,-53287.95266,-55123.02039,-5131.095738,92963.75123,184430.9087,180646.3185,21137.78348,-252747.0452,-475735.34,-436097.8969,-33470.52706,583046.8515,1024123.527;
0,0,0,0,192,1184.107549,3229.595901,4321.651839,-104.2768198,-12455.61648,-25344.84529,-20852.91355,14642.78081,67162.133,88643.95935,29331.92183,-103721.9759,-215885.8219,-175668.2952,63339.97258,366040.1121,463007.7228,161145.8379,-426631.9431;
0,0,0,0,192,1035.320732,2197.653181,1181.837405,-4776.384006,-12614.95411,-10733.55999,10443.54925,39434.88701,40860.0242,-11919.57845,-90391.52336,-109544.5177,-4764.383231,169447.4417,238928.2291,63214.86651,-273067.0285,-452649.3406,-197417.4769;
0,0,0,0,192,884.6792681,1293.804398,-933.634351,-6033.445815,-7367.269353,3768.214436,22179.4179,22745.61092,-13409.71654,-59759.11695,-51183.66478,39553.74618,132447.0485,93359.81585,-98263.14966,-255824.9417,-144286.083,212696.4921,445204.5408;
0,0,0,0,192,735.8924507,540.3053094,-2124.343367,-5057.868211,-969.9812354,11405.43117,15940.52452,-5622.481002,-37623.47011,-29881.32575,35855.80045,87872.36995,28692.89466,-112944.5884,-154561.6584,24454.28757,254280.9736,202369.5839,-178659.2813;
0,0,0,0,192,592.6239049,-54.49033533,-2567.50857,-2988.296704,3941.876267,11526.38431,2233.953421,-22136.82236,-24139.16168,20459.96219,60268.45865,14532.0698,-88098.13253,-93277.95948,64910.42847,192595.8473,49803.13745,-244897.5404,-254777.9707;
0,0,0,0,192,458.4013779,-495.3380524,-2477.176593,-714.5839156,6392.684212,6873.986266,-9352.41825,-21134.06087,3844.754647,42020.47316,20505.10932,-58980.138,-70793.54333,51327.19794,141815.5672,6229.868714,-208390.0472,-130756.2533,224730.6889;
0,0,0,0,192,336.5298736,-798.086388,-2066.223865,1211.650343,6609.005295,832.2069828,-14542.95731,-9394.727768,23888.17206,29260.48864,-28610.53289,-63533.47519,18266.13986,110340.0964,20413.44929,-159630.1792,-99650.79156,191428.6434,224840.2275;
0,0,0,0,192,230.010273,-986.6727322,-1517.645248,2561.671612,5397.538212,-4248.815769,-13851.25499,3944.496017,28647.88724,2246.348802,-50351.46819,-19936.09886,77156.40402,55808.14847,-103790.0999,-116346.81,120768.0917,206007.3722,-114289.9057;
0,0,0,0,192,141.4654422,-1089.461027,-968.7547191,3346.025684,3627.717551,-7474.097775,-9965.085871,13492.9252,22500.21035,-20544.91549,-44251.15549,26525.3978,78409.54708,-27774.42335,-127872.1365,18879.12551,194650.9903,7368.517829,-279197.6607;
0,0,0,0,192,73.07564879,-1135.312342,-508.5655728,3706.949976,1946.428626,-9020.436512,-5497.089494,18315.25514,12841.39554,-32819.98602,-26305.72752,53592.96081,48907.83539,-81344.97478,-84369.59991,116249.2281,137093.641,-157744.2065,-212101.4947;
0,0,0,0,192,26.52487642,-1149.801347,-185.5323873,3822.418606,714.8963246,-9523.125445,-2036.182875,19914.17359,4805.440196,-36987.23947,-9962.723932,63039.66842,18780.08487,-100646.6018,-32907.74918,152629.087,54418.22672,-222018.2854,-85848.08848;
0,0,0,0,192,2.959359616,-1151.972632,-20.71532046,3839.781056,79.90093794,-9599.042127,-227.8620289,20156.93483,538.572741,-37623.95402,-1118.549352,64493.6094,2112.7619,-103642.0699,-3710.543262,158327.7533,6151.495274,-232190.8611,-9731.39151;
1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0;
0,0,4,0,-16,0,36,0,-64,0,100,0,-144,0,196,0,-256,0,324,0,-400,0,484,0;
0,0,0,24,192,840,2688,7056,16128,33264,63360,113256,192192,312312,489216,742560,1096704,1581408,2232576,3093048,4213440,5653032,7480704,9775920;
0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144,169,196,225,256,289,324,361,400,441,484,529]

S=[1,0.998458667,0.993839419,0.986156496,0.975433581,0.96170373,0.945009268,0.925401657,0.902941342,0.87769756,0.84974813,0.819179209,0.786085032,0.750567618,0.712736454,0.672708162,0.630606134,0.586560159,0.540706014,0.493185053,0.444143767,0.393733335,0.342109153,0.289430364;
1,0.98618496,0.945121551,0.877944359,0.786509494,0.673343309,0.541572595,0.394838187,0.237194368,0.07299685,-0.093217576,-0.256856394,-0.413398249,-0.558517877,-0.688205612,-0.798878172,-0.887477663,-0.951556077,-0.98934292,-0.999794139,-0.982620967,-0.938297899,-0.868049586,-0.773816993;
1,0.961939766,0.850656228,0.67462034,0.447232036,0.18580022,-0.089774795,-0.35851611,-0.599967012,-0.795748145,-0.930956556,-0.99530012,-0.983880972,-0.897568346,-0.742932397,-0.531744087,-0.280079168,-0.007094493,0.266430219,0.519674138,0.733360219,0.891222577,0.981244656,0.996573933;
1,0.926320082,0.716137789,0.400425549,0.025706666,-0.352800347,-0.679318759,-0.90573287,-0.998678335,-0.944458724,-0.751063831,-0.446992295,-0.077052048,0.304242576,0.640704064,0.882751506,0.994716832,0.960100849,0.784004562,0.492377492,0.128193756,-0.254880591,-0.600395776,-0.857436738;
1,0.880202983,0.549514582,0.087165765,-0.396067449,-0.784405265,-0.984804259,-0.949250027,-0.686261152,-0.258848199,0.230583238,0.664768308,0.939678856,0.989447956,0.802151229,0.422663852,-0.058091262,-0.524928056,-0.86599522,-0.999575095,-0.89366274,-0.573634124,-0.116166194,0.369134463;
1,0.824724024,0.360339432,-0.230362851,-0.740310987,-0.990741662,-0.893865914,-0.483643725,0.096120716,0.642189852,0.963138082,0.946456378,0.597992543,0.039901255,-0.532177495,-0.917700386,-0.981521616,-0.701268527,-0.175184388,0.412310981,0.85526993,0.998412337,0.79155935,0.307223688;
1,0.761249282,0.15900094,-0.51917058,-0.949437402,-0.926346503,-0.460923818,0.224590651,0.802862762,0.997766752,0.716235686,0.092701052,-0.575098468,-0.968287643,-0.899118079,-0.400618342,0.289177228,0.840890257,0.991076981,0.668023024,0.025987114,-0.62845768,-0.98281303,-0.867873748;
1,0.691341716,-0.044093263,-0.75230874,-0.996111568,-0.624998222,0.131936882,0.807425162,0.984476513,0.553794202,-0.218754445,-0.856262349,-0.965185319,-0.4782834,0.303870785,0.8984405,0.93838801,0.399053054,-0.386623964,-0.933631603,-0.904292986,-0.316719326,0.46637042,0.96156198;
1,0.616722682,-0.239306267,-0.911893888,-0.885465021,-0.180278837,0.663100925,0.998177599,0.568096607,-0.297461473,-0.934999082,-0.855808809,-0.120594327,0.707062296,0.992717038,0.517399932,-0.354532491,-0.954696389,-0.823033344,-0.060470273,0.748446566,0.98363822,0.464817436,-0.410311308;
1,0.539229548,-0.418462989,-0.990524765,-0.649777453,0.289766361,0.96227862,0.74801177,-0.155578523,-0.915796843,-0.832070912,0.0184424,0.851960286,0.90036192,0.119043216,-0.771978681,-0.951590646,-0.254272907,0.677367717,0.984786282,0.384684007,-0.569920316,-0.999319756,-0.507805164;
1,0.460770452,-0.575381181,-0.991007746,-0.337872993,0.679643962,0.964192705,0.208899055,-0.771683681,-0.920037132,-0.07616817,0.849845048,0.859335144,-0.057932562,-0.91272237,-0.783178435,0.190991406,0.959184828,0.692936648,-0.320615363,-0.98839682,-0.590232736,0.444473211,0.99983298;
1,0.383277318,-0.706196995,-0.924615899,-0.002571609,0.92264462,0.70982912,-0.378521817,-0.999986774,-0.38802268,0.702546189,0.926562719,0.007714758,-0.920648935,-0.713442468,0.373756304,0.999947095,0.392757778,-0.698876799,-0.928485029,-0.012857704,0.918628896,0.717036943,-0.368980903;
1,0.308658284,-0.809460128,-0.808351431,0.310451397,0.999998222,0.306864073,-0.810565945,-0.807239861,0.312243405,0.999992888,0.305068772,-0.811668881,-0.80612542,0.314034304,0.999983998,0.303272386,-0.81276893,-0.805008112,0.315824085,0.999971552,0.301474921,-0.813866089,-0.803887941;
1,0.238750718,-0.88599619,-0.66181517,0.569978496,0.93398072,-0.124001362,-0.993191548,-0.350249028,0.825947135,0.74463997,-0.47038048,-0.969247324,0.007563492,0.972858903,0.456978031,-0.754651237,-0.81732508,0.364377338,0.991315782,0.10897737,-0.939278931,-0.557484408,0.673079326;
1,0.175275976,-0.938556665,-0.504288846,0.761777225,0.771331339,-0.491385519,-0.943587492,0.160609082,0.999889319,0.18990407,-0.933318077,-0.517080544,0.752054483,0.78071471,-0.478373418,-0.948409446,0.145906635,0.999557301,0.204490127,-0.927872888,-0.529757779,0.742165265,0.789925261;
1,0.119797017,-0.971297349,-0.352514068,0.886837082,0.564994942,-0.751467664,-0.745042111,0.572960019,0.882319914,-0.361561431,-0.968947876,0.1294073,0.999953093,0.110175495,-0.973555702,-0.343433634,0.891271052,0.556976861,-0.757822719,-0.738546663,0.580871344,0.877719972,-0.370574875;
1,0.073679918,-0.989142539,-0.2194398,0.956805927,0.360434564,-0.903692348,-0.49360252,0.830955162,0.616051936,-0.74017385,-0.725123833,0.633319721,0.818449723,-0.512713105,-0.894003042,0.380972963,0.950143155,-0.240960024,-0.985650985,0.095714657,0.999755481,0.051609146,-0.992150366;
1,0.038060234,-0.997102837,-0.113960168,0.988428136,0.18919978,-0.97402616,-0.263343106,0.95398036,0.335960537,-0.928406887,-0.406631304,0.897453922,0.474945916,-0.861300817,-0.540508536,0.820157054,0.602939275,-0.774261035,-0.661876387,0.723878695,0.716978371,-0.669301966,-0.76792595;
1,0.01381504,-0.999618289,-0.041434573,0.998473449,0.069022474,-0.996566352,-0.096557681,0.993898456,0.124019175,-0.990471796,-0.151385989,0.986288989,0.178637233,-0.981353228,-0.2057521,0.975668281,0.232709893,-0.969238489,-0.259490029,0.962068758,0.286072066,-0.954164565,-0.312435708;
1,0.001541333,-0.999995249,-0.004623985,0.999980994,0.007706592,-0.999957238,-0.010789127,0.999923978,0.013871559,-0.999881217,-0.016953859,0.999828954,0.020035998,-0.999767189,-0.023117946,0.999695925,0.026199675,-0.99961516,-0.029281155,0.999524896,0.032362357,-0.999425133,-0.035443251;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: Are your real eigenvalues the same as theirs?  In some cases, folks just ignore a complex eigenvalue.

Comment: If you have the eigenvectors as well as the eigenvalues (easily calculated using BLAS/LAPACK, I don't know about MATLAB) you can easily verify the eigenvalues.

Comment: It would very much help us on the Fortran side if you can tell us what the order of these matrices are, what evals you are finding, and what evals you are expecting

Comment: @TimRoberts No, my real eigenvalues are different from theirs.

Comment: @IanBush The matrices are 24X24. Actually when I generate the matrices of order less than or equal to 23X23, all my eigenvalues are real and match with the existing results. However as soon as I increase the order of the matrix to more than 23, I end up with complex eigenvalues, though according to the paper regardless of the order all eigenvalues should be real. I tried using Fortran, but due to little to no knowledge about it all I could do was import the matrices that I generated in MATLAB. But I couldn't use the RGG subroutine (EISPACK) and I couldn't get any help on the internet.

Comment: Can you *edit the question* to include the order, and also tell us what evals you are expecting, and what you are getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell the matrices you give have 2 complex evals, a complex conjugate pair. I checked using the Fortran program below, which uses both EISPACK and LAPACK, the latter having superseded the former decades ago. Both give the same answers where you can calculate an eval. I say this as note the comment at http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/dggev.f.html which is the documentation for the LAPACK routine:

```
*  A generalized eigenvalue for a pair of matrices (A,B) is a scalar
*  lambda or a ratio alpha/beta = lambda, such that A - lambda*B is
*  singular. It is usually represented as the pair (alpha,beta), as
*  there is a reasonable interpretation for beta=0, and even for both
*  being zero.
```

In your case beta is zero in four cases, I am assuming due to the 4 columns of your matrices which contain zeros. In these cases you can't calculate lambda, so I quote the real and imaginary parts of alpha, and beta in the results below, before calculating lambda where possible.

LAPACK was the one acquired by apt get on my machine. The relevant parts of EISPACK were downloaded from http://www.netlib.org/cgi-bin/netlibfiles.pl?filename=/eispack/rgg.f and the compiled into a little library with

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/Downloads/eispack$ unzip netlibfiles.zip 
Archive:  netlibfiles.zip
  inflating: eispack/epslon.f        
  inflating: eispack/qzhes.f         
  inflating: eispack/qzit.f          
  inflating: eispack/qzval.f         
  inflating: eispack/qzvec.f         
  inflating: eispack/rgg.f           
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/Downloads/eispack$ cd eispack/
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/Downloads/eispack/eispack$ gfortran -c -O *f
qzvec.f:92:72:

   92 |   610       r = r + (betm * a(i,j) - alfm * b(i,j)) * b(j,en)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 610 at (1)
qzvec.f:207:72:

  207 |          do 880 i = 1, n
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 880 at (1)
qzvec.f:211:72:

  211 |   860       zz = zz + z(i,k) * b(k,j)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 860 at (1)
qzvec.f:228:72:

  228 |   900    z(i,j) = z(i,j) / d
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 900 at (1)
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/Downloads/eispack/eispack$ ar r eispack.a *.o
ar: creating eispack.a
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/Downloads/eispack/eispack$
```

The data file was created from what you have above:

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ cat eig.dat
0 0 0 0 192 1917.04064 10332.51505 40092.51227 125681.1486 338350.2206 811892.8294 1779728.921 3625982.355 6953387.916 12670976.81 22100000 37132930.27 60353006.25 95276316.19 146559937.4 220274060.5 324208411.9 468219308 664618721.8 
0 0 0 0 192 1893.475124 10051.90014 38308.22391 117609.6433 309187.9535 722364.2569 1537115.973 3030677.025 5606681.841 9824567.083 16426180.74 26355891.41 40770017.02 61031174.08 88683247.04 125403139.6 172926323.5 232944447.3 306974887 
0 0 0 0 192 1846.924351 9507.779872 34923.83828 102685.9158 256815.0258 566753.8301 1130503.089 2072244.588 3531888.862 5644710.273 8510616.36 12154554.65 16481872.51 21234784.98 25958063.51 29983201.26 32440241.94 32304892.86 28485362.66 
0 0 0 0 192 1778.534558 8732.953666 30281.20319 83090.50097 191433.6927 383369.9941 681577.7806 1089000.57 1571702.814 2043718.6 2360415.659 2327150.205 1728131.214 376286.8361 -1820993.208 -4791939.112 -8243585.409 -11638086.16 -14220529.21 
0 0 0 0 192 1689.989727 7773.203992 24831.36406 61515.88289 124689.9821 212051.9399 303583.89 356337.2627 308129.1939 94242.56924 -323226.8121 -920239.2345 -1583058.32 -2104105.201 -2214813.175 -1659107.74 -295993.1841 1796496.926 4254923.427 
0 0 0 0 192 1583.470126 6683.555129 19072.50505 40639.69537 66711.57632 81796.22718 60590.29663 -21861.2573 -171429.7577 -355062.5907 -492927.1661 -475398.2758 -208930.4549 320950.1747 997476.1882 1566265.895 1699768.472 1129529.762 -194208.6509 
0 0 0 0 192 1461.598622 5523.845413 13484.72812 22648.14037 23924.65349 4088.400074 -44523.67789 -110266.4937 -154796.0153 -124116.6074 18352.09343 250026.0416 467393.1673 513093.6957 258167.4211 -292568.7362 -936296.041 -1313188.428 -1070939.742 
0 0 0 0 192 1327.376095 4354.022806 8472.235861 8915.430969 -1775.330646 -26379.77787 -53287.95266 -55123.02039 -5131.095738 92963.75123 184430.9087 180646.3185 21137.78348 -252747.0452 -475735.34 -436097.8969 -33470.52706 583046.8515 1024123.527 
0 0 0 0 192 1184.107549 3229.595901 4321.651839 -104.2768198 -12455.61648 -25344.84529 -20852.91355 14642.78081 67162.133 88643.95935 29331.92183 -103721.9759 -215885.8219 -175668.2952 63339.97258 366040.1121 463007.7228 161145.8379 -426631.9431 
0 0 0 0 192 1035.320732 2197.653181 1181.837405 -4776.384006 -12614.95411 -10733.55999 10443.54925 39434.88701 40860.0242 -11919.57845 -90391.52336 -109544.5177 -4764.383231 169447.4417 238928.2291 63214.86651 -273067.0285 -452649.3406 -197417.4769 
0 0 0 0 192 884.6792681 1293.804398 -933.634351 -6033.445815 -7367.269353 3768.214436 22179.4179 22745.61092 -13409.71654 -59759.11695 -51183.66478 39553.74618 132447.0485 93359.81585 -98263.14966 -255824.9417 -144286.083 212696.4921 445204.5408 
0 0 0 0 192 735.8924507 540.3053094 -2124.343367 -5057.868211 -969.9812354 11405.43117 15940.52452 -5622.481002 -37623.47011 -29881.32575 35855.80045 87872.36995 28692.89466 -112944.5884 -154561.6584 24454.28757 254280.9736 202369.5839 -178659.2813 
0 0 0 0 192 592.6239049 -54.49033533 -2567.50857 -2988.296704 3941.876267 11526.38431 2233.953421 -22136.82236 -24139.16168 20459.96219 60268.45865 14532.0698 -88098.13253 -93277.95948 64910.42847 192595.8473 49803.13745 -244897.5404 -254777.9707 
0 0 0 0 192 458.4013779 -495.3380524 -2477.176593 -714.5839156 6392.684212 6873.986266 -9352.41825 -21134.06087 3844.754647 42020.47316 20505.10932 -58980.138 -70793.54333 51327.19794 141815.5672 6229.868714 -208390.0472 -130756.2533 224730.6889 
0 0 0 0 192 336.5298736 -798.086388 -2066.223865 1211.650343 6609.005295 832.2069828 -14542.95731 -9394.727768 23888.17206 29260.48864 -28610.53289 -63533.47519 18266.13986 110340.0964 20413.44929 -159630.1792 -99650.79156 191428.6434 224840.2275 
0 0 0 0 192 230.010273 -986.6727322 -1517.645248 2561.671612 5397.538212 -4248.815769 -13851.25499 3944.496017 28647.88724 2246.348802 -50351.46819 -19936.09886 77156.40402 55808.14847 -103790.0999 -116346.81 120768.0917 206007.3722 -114289.9057 
0 0 0 0 192 141.4654422 -1089.461027 -968.7547191 3346.025684 3627.717551 -7474.097775 -9965.085871 13492.9252 22500.21035 -20544.91549 -44251.15549 26525.3978 78409.54708 -27774.42335 -127872.1365 18879.12551 194650.9903 7368.517829 -279197.6607 
0 0 0 0 192 73.07564879 -1135.312342 -508.5655728 3706.949976 1946.428626 -9020.436512 -5497.089494 18315.25514 12841.39554 -32819.98602 -26305.72752 53592.96081 48907.83539 -81344.97478 -84369.59991 116249.2281 137093.641 -157744.2065 -212101.4947 
0 0 0 0 192 26.52487642 -1149.801347 -185.5323873 3822.418606 714.8963246 -9523.125445 -2036.182875 19914.17359 4805.440196 -36987.23947 -9962.723932 63039.66842 18780.08487 -100646.6018 -32907.74918 152629.087 54418.22672 -222018.2854 -85848.08848 
0 0 0 0 192 2.959359616 -1151.972632 -20.71532046 3839.781056 79.90093794 -9599.042127 -227.8620289 20156.93483 538.572741 -37623.95402 -1118.549352 64493.6094 2112.7619 -103642.0699 -3710.543262 158327.7533 6151.495274 -232190.8611 -9731.39151 
1 0 -1 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 -1 0 
0 0 4 0 -16 0 36 0 -64 0 100 0 -144 0 196 0 -256 0 324 0 -400 0 484 0 
0 0 0 24 192 840 2688 7056 16128 33264 63360 113256 192192 312312 489216 742560 1096704 1581408 2232576 3093048 4213440 5653032 7480704 9775920 
0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 121 144 169 196 225 256 289 324 361 400 441 484 529

1 0.998458667 0.993839419 0.986156496 0.975433581 0.96170373 0.945009268 0.925401657 0.902941342 0.87769756 0.84974813 0.819179209 0.786085032 0.750567618 0.712736454 0.672708162 0.630606134 0.586560159 0.540706014 0.493185053 0.444143767 0.393733335 0.342109153 0.289430364 
1 0.98618496 0.945121551 0.877944359 0.786509494 0.673343309 0.541572595 0.394838187 0.237194368 0.07299685 -0.093217576 -0.256856394 -0.413398249 -0.558517877 -0.688205612 -0.798878172 -0.887477663 -0.951556077 -0.98934292 -0.999794139 -0.982620967 -0.938297899 -0.868049586 -0.773816993 
1 0.961939766 0.850656228 0.67462034 0.447232036 0.18580022 -0.089774795 -0.35851611 -0.599967012 -0.795748145 -0.930956556 -0.99530012 -0.983880972 -0.897568346 -0.742932397 -0.531744087 -0.280079168 -0.007094493 0.266430219 0.519674138 0.733360219 0.891222577 0.981244656 0.996573933 
1 0.926320082 0.716137789 0.400425549 0.025706666 -0.352800347 -0.679318759 -0.90573287 -0.998678335 -0.944458724 -0.751063831 -0.446992295 -0.077052048 0.304242576 0.640704064 0.882751506 0.994716832 0.960100849 0.784004562 0.492377492 0.128193756 -0.254880591 -0.600395776 -0.857436738 
1 0.880202983 0.549514582 0.087165765 -0.396067449 -0.784405265 -0.984804259 -0.949250027 -0.686261152 -0.258848199 0.230583238 0.664768308 0.939678856 0.989447956 0.802151229 0.422663852 -0.058091262 -0.524928056 -0.86599522 -0.999575095 -0.89366274 -0.573634124 -0.116166194 0.369134463 
1 0.824724024 0.360339432 -0.230362851 -0.740310987 -0.990741662 -0.893865914 -0.483643725 0.096120716 0.642189852 0.963138082 0.946456378 0.597992543 0.039901255 -0.532177495 -0.917700386 -0.981521616 -0.701268527 -0.175184388 0.412310981 0.85526993 0.998412337 0.79155935 0.307223688 
1 0.761249282 0.15900094 -0.51917058 -0.949437402 -0.926346503 -0.460923818 0.224590651 0.802862762 0.997766752 0.716235686 0.092701052 -0.575098468 -0.968287643 -0.899118079 -0.400618342 0.289177228 0.840890257 0.991076981 0.668023024 0.025987114 -0.62845768 -0.98281303 -0.867873748 
1 0.691341716 -0.044093263 -0.75230874 -0.996111568 -0.624998222 0.131936882 0.807425162 0.984476513 0.553794202 -0.218754445 -0.856262349 -0.965185319 -0.4782834 0.303870785 0.8984405 0.93838801 0.399053054 -0.386623964 -0.933631603 -0.904292986 -0.316719326 0.46637042 0.96156198 
1 0.616722682 -0.239306267 -0.911893888 -0.885465021 -0.180278837 0.663100925 0.998177599 0.568096607 -0.297461473 -0.934999082 -0.855808809 -0.120594327 0.707062296 0.992717038 0.517399932 -0.354532491 -0.954696389 -0.823033344 -0.060470273 0.748446566 0.98363822 0.464817436 -0.410311308 
1 0.539229548 -0.418462989 -0.990524765 -0.649777453 0.289766361 0.96227862 0.74801177 -0.155578523 -0.915796843 -0.832070912 0.0184424 0.851960286 0.90036192 0.119043216 -0.771978681 -0.951590646 -0.254272907 0.677367717 0.984786282 0.384684007 -0.569920316 -0.999319756 -0.507805164 
1 0.460770452 -0.575381181 -0.991007746 -0.337872993 0.679643962 0.964192705 0.208899055 -0.771683681 -0.920037132 -0.07616817 0.849845048 0.859335144 -0.057932562 -0.91272237 -0.783178435 0.190991406 0.959184828 0.692936648 -0.320615363 -0.98839682 -0.590232736 0.444473211 0.99983298 
1 0.383277318 -0.706196995 -0.924615899 -0.002571609 0.92264462 0.70982912 -0.378521817 -0.999986774 -0.38802268 0.702546189 0.926562719 0.007714758 -0.920648935 -0.713442468 0.373756304 0.999947095 0.392757778 -0.698876799 -0.928485029 -0.012857704 0.918628896 0.717036943 -0.368980903 
1 0.308658284 -0.809460128 -0.808351431 0.310451397 0.999998222 0.306864073 -0.810565945 -0.807239861 0.312243405 0.999992888 0.305068772 -0.811668881 -0.80612542 0.314034304 0.999983998 0.303272386 -0.81276893 -0.805008112 0.315824085 0.999971552 0.301474921 -0.813866089 -0.803887941 
1 0.238750718 -0.88599619 -0.66181517 0.569978496 0.93398072 -0.124001362 -0.993191548 -0.350249028 0.825947135 0.74463997 -0.47038048 -0.969247324 0.007563492 0.972858903 0.456978031 -0.754651237 -0.81732508 0.364377338 0.991315782 0.10897737 -0.939278931 -0.557484408 0.673079326 
1 0.175275976 -0.938556665 -0.504288846 0.761777225 0.771331339 -0.491385519 -0.943587492 0.160609082 0.999889319 0.18990407 -0.933318077 -0.517080544 0.752054483 0.78071471 -0.478373418 -0.948409446 0.145906635 0.999557301 0.204490127 -0.927872888 -0.529757779 0.742165265 0.789925261 
1 0.119797017 -0.971297349 -0.352514068 0.886837082 0.564994942 -0.751467664 -0.745042111 0.572960019 0.882319914 -0.361561431 -0.968947876 0.1294073 0.999953093 0.110175495 -0.973555702 -0.343433634 0.891271052 0.556976861 -0.757822719 -0.738546663 0.580871344 0.877719972 -0.370574875 
1 0.073679918 -0.989142539 -0.2194398 0.956805927 0.360434564 -0.903692348 -0.49360252 0.830955162 0.616051936 -0.74017385 -0.725123833 0.633319721 0.818449723 -0.512713105 -0.894003042 0.380972963 0.950143155 -0.240960024 -0.985650985 0.095714657 0.999755481 0.051609146 -0.992150366 
1 0.038060234 -0.997102837 -0.113960168 0.988428136 0.18919978 -0.97402616 -0.263343106 0.95398036 0.335960537 -0.928406887 -0.406631304 0.897453922 0.474945916 -0.861300817 -0.540508536 0.820157054 0.602939275 -0.774261035 -0.661876387 0.723878695 0.716978371 -0.669301966 -0.76792595 
1 0.01381504 -0.999618289 -0.041434573 0.998473449 0.069022474 -0.996566352 -0.096557681 0.993898456 0.124019175 -0.990471796 -0.151385989 0.986288989 0.178637233 -0.981353228 -0.2057521 0.975668281 0.232709893 -0.969238489 -0.259490029 0.962068758 0.286072066 -0.954164565 -0.312435708 
1 0.001541333 -0.999995249 -0.004623985 0.999980994 0.007706592 -0.999957238 -0.010789127 0.999923978 0.013871559 -0.999881217 -0.016953859 0.999828954 0.020035998 -0.999767189 -0.023117946 0.999695925 0.026199675 -0.99961516 -0.029281155 0.999524896 0.032362357 -0.999425133 -0.035443251 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The program, its compilation are

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ cat eig.f90
Program eig

  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only : wp => real64

  Implicit None

  Integer, Parameter :: n = 24
  
  Real( wp ), Dimension( 1:n, 1:n ) :: H
  Real( wp ), Dimension( 1:n, 1:n ) :: S

  Integer :: unit

  Open( newunit = unit, file = 'eig.dat' )
  Read( unit, * ) H
  Read( unit, * ) S
  Close( unit )

  Write( *, * ) 'Lapack: '
  Call lapack( H, S )

  Write( *, * ) 'Eispack: '
  Call eispack( H, S )

Contains

  Subroutine lapack( H, S )

    Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only : wp => real64

    Implicit None

    Real( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Intent( In ) :: H
    Real( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Intent( In ) :: S

    Complex( wp ) :: lambda
    
    Real( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: A
    Real( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: B
    Real( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: QR

    Real( wp ), Dimension( 1:1, 1:1 ) :: Ql_dummy

    Real( wp ), Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: alphar
    Real( wp ), Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: alphai
    Real( wp ), Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: beta
    Real( wp ), Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: work

    Real( wp ), Dimension( 1:1 ) :: twork

    Integer :: n
    Integer :: lwork
    Integer :: info
    Integer :: i

    n = Size( H, Dim = 1 )

    ! H and S would be overwritten
    A = H
    B = S

    ! Space for evals and evecs
    Allocate( alphar( 1:n ) )
    Allocate( alphai( 1:n ) )
    Allocate( beta( 1:n ) )
    Allocate( QR( 1:n, 1:n ) )

    ! Calculate and allocate the worksize
    Call dggev( 'N', 'V', n, A, Size( A, Dim = 1 ), B, Size( B, Dim = 1 ), &
         alphar, alphai, beta, &
         QL_dummy, Size( QL_dummy, Dim = 1 ), &
         QR, Size( QR, Dim = 1 ), &
         twork, -1, info )

    ! Allocate workspace
    lwork = Nint( twork( 1 ) )
    Allocate( work( 1:lwork ) )

    ! Solve eval problem
    Call dggev( 'N', 'V', n, A, Size( A, Dim = 1 ), B, Size( B, Dim = 1 ), &
         alphar, alphai, beta, &
         QL_dummy, Size( QL_dummy, Dim = 1 ), &
         QR, Size( QR, Dim = 1 ), &
         work, Size( work ), info )
    Write( *, * ) 'info = ', info

    ! Report results
    Write( *, * ) 'Evals - last column reports lambda where appropriate'
    Do i = 1, n
       If( Abs( beta( i ) ) > 1.0e-16_wp ) Then
          lambda = Cmplx( alphar( i ), alphai( i ), wp ) / beta( i )
          Write( *, '( i2, 1x, 3( e18.6, 1x ), 5x, e18.6, " + ", e18.6, "i" )' ) &
               i, alphar( i ), alphai( i ), beta( i ), lambda
       Else
          Write( *, '( i2, 1x, 3( e18.6, 1x ) )' ) i, alphar( i ), alphai( i ), beta( i )
       End If
    End Do
    Write( *, * )

  End Subroutine lapack

  Subroutine eispack( H, S )

    Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only : wp => real64

    Implicit None

    Real( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Intent( In ) :: H
    Real( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Intent( In ) :: S

    Complex( wp ) :: lambda
    
    Real( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: A
    Real( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: B
    Real( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: QR

    Real( wp ), Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: alphar
    Real( wp ), Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: alphai
    Real( wp ), Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: beta

    Integer :: n
    Integer :: info
    Integer :: i

    n = Size( H, Dim = 1 )

    ! H and S would be overwritten
    A = H
    B = S

    ! Space for evals and evecs
    Allocate( alphar( 1:n ) )
    Allocate( alphai( 1:n ) )
    Allocate( beta( 1:n ) )
    Allocate( QR( 1:n, 1:n ) )

    ! Calc evals and evecs by eispack
    Call rgg( Size( A, Dim = 1 ), n, A, B, alphar, alphai, beta, 1, QR, info )
    Write( *, * ) 'info = ', info

    ! Report results
    Write( *, * ) 'Evals - last column reports lambda where appropriate'
    Do i = 1, n
       If( Abs( beta( i ) ) > 1.0e-16_wp ) Then
          lambda = Cmplx( alphar( i ), alphai( i ), wp ) / beta( i )
          Write( *, '( i2, 1x, 3( e18.6, 1x ), 5x, e18.6, " + ", e18.6, "i" )' ) &
               i, alphar( i ), alphai( i ), beta( i ), lambda
       Else
          Write( *, '( i2, 1x, 3( e18.6, 1x ) )' ) i, alphar( i ), alphai( i ), beta( i )
       End If
    End Do
    Write( *, * )

  End Subroutine eispack
  
End Program eig
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -O -g eig.f90 eispack.a -llapack
```

And the results are (note the complex conjugate pair)

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 Lapack: 
 info =            0
 Evals - last column reports lambda where appropriate
 1      -0.608116E+01       0.000000E+00       0.187802E-11           -0.323806E+13 +       0.000000E+00i
 2       0.370614E+03       0.000000E+00       0.262593E-05            0.141137E+09 +       0.000000E+00i
 3      -0.166285E+05       0.000000E+00       0.150764E-02           -0.110295E+08 +       0.000000E+00i
 4       0.356929E+06       0.000000E+00       0.387651E-01            0.920748E+07 +       0.000000E+00i
 5       0.376034E+06       0.000000E+00       0.654174E-01            0.574823E+07 +       0.000000E+00i
 6       0.881731E+05       0.129854E+06       0.121455E+00            0.725976E+06 +       0.106916E+07i
 7       0.154526E+06      -0.227573E+06       0.212853E+00            0.725976E+06 +      -0.106916E+07i
 8       0.400747E+05       0.000000E+00       0.327119E-01            0.122508E+07 +       0.000000E+00i
 9       0.353978E+05       0.000000E+00       0.623272E-01            0.567936E+06 +       0.000000E+00i
10       0.177191E+05       0.000000E+00       0.342541E-01            0.517282E+06 +       0.000000E+00i
11       0.703041E+04       0.000000E+00       0.224366E-01            0.313346E+06 +       0.000000E+00i
12       0.250241E+04       0.000000E+00       0.142464E-01            0.175653E+06 +       0.000000E+00i
13       0.816411E+02       0.000000E+00       0.815119E-03            0.100159E+06 +       0.000000E+00i
14       0.127044E+04       0.000000E+00       0.141856E-01            0.895583E+05 +       0.000000E+00i
15       0.396171E+04       0.000000E+00       0.991827E-01            0.399436E+05 +       0.000000E+00i
16       0.461457E+05       0.000000E+00       0.315689E+01            0.146175E+05 +       0.000000E+00i
17       0.109954E+05       0.000000E+00       0.288969E+01            0.380504E+04 +       0.000000E+00i
18       0.188721E+02       0.000000E+00       0.309986E+01            0.608807E+01 +       0.000000E+00i
19       0.123631E-03       0.000000E+00       0.139487E-06            0.886324E+03 +       0.000000E+00i
20       0.158220E+04       0.000000E+00       0.320845E+01            0.493134E+03 +       0.000000E+00i
21       0.899768E+03       0.000000E+00       0.000000E+00
22       0.376730E-01       0.000000E+00       0.000000E+00
23       0.366102E-01       0.000000E+00       0.000000E+00
24       0.960100E-01       0.000000E+00       0.000000E+00

 Eispack: 
 info =            0
 Evals - last column reports lambda where appropriate
 1      -0.346410E+01       0.000000E+00       0.000000E+00
 2      -0.546079E+03       0.000000E+00       0.000000E+00
 3       0.144715E+08       0.000000E+00       0.000000E+00
 4       0.528475E+03       0.000000E+00       0.000000E+00
 5      -0.233202E+08       0.000000E+00       0.719984E-05           -0.323898E+13 +       0.000000E+00i
 6       0.278909E+06       0.000000E+00       0.197617E-02            0.141136E+09 +       0.000000E+00i
 7      -0.250582E+05       0.000000E+00       0.227192E-02           -0.110295E+08 +       0.000000E+00i
 8       0.491054E+04       0.000000E+00       0.533321E-03            0.920746E+07 +       0.000000E+00i
 9       0.777637E+05       0.000000E+00       0.135281E-01            0.574829E+07 +       0.000000E+00i
10       0.199724E+04       0.294137E+04       0.275110E-02            0.725977E+06 +       0.106916E+07i
11       0.335291E+04      -0.493790E+04       0.461849E-02            0.725977E+06 +      -0.106916E+07i
12       0.358837E+04       0.000000E+00       0.292908E-02            0.122508E+07 +       0.000000E+00i
13       0.981532E+03       0.000000E+00       0.172823E-02            0.567941E+06 +       0.000000E+00i
14       0.138597E+03       0.000000E+00       0.267934E-03            0.517279E+06 +       0.000000E+00i
15       0.286093E+03       0.000000E+00       0.913029E-03            0.313345E+06 +       0.000000E+00i
16       0.518162E+02       0.000000E+00       0.294991E-03            0.175653E+06 +       0.000000E+00i
17       0.957124E+00       0.000000E+00       0.955594E-05            0.100160E+06 +       0.000000E+00i
18       0.104269E+01       0.000000E+00       0.116426E-04            0.895582E+05 +       0.000000E+00i
19       0.874474E+02       0.000000E+00       0.218927E-02            0.399436E+05 +       0.000000E+00i
20       0.185986E+04       0.000000E+00       0.127235E+00            0.146175E+05 +       0.000000E+00i
21       0.968367E+04       0.000000E+00       0.254496E+01            0.380504E+04 +       0.000000E+00i
22       0.171890E+02       0.000000E+00       0.282339E+01            0.608807E+01 +       0.000000E+00i
23       0.100843E-04       0.000000E+00       0.113655E-07            0.887279E+03 +       0.000000E+00i
24       0.234040E+03       0.000000E+00       0.474598E+00            0.493134E+03 +       0.000000E+00i
```

Given all this I suggest one of the following is occurring:

- The original paper is wrong
- The data you quote is wrong
- I am misunderstanding something you are saying

I don't know if it is possible *a priori* to say whether a given problem has a complex eval without solving the problem itself.

Comment: I am receiving the same lambdas from Mathematica, including `725960. + 1.06915*10^6 I, 725960. - 1.06915*10^6 I`  plus 4x  ComplexInfinity. It probably calls LAPACK anyway, but I don't know.

Comment: @Ian Bush thank you so much for taking your time to answer this. This problem will have complex eigenvalues. In the research paper the authors probably ignored the complex ones and took only the real ones. I'm not sure why eig() command is giving a different answer but when I tried to solve for determinant(H-λS)=0, I am able to get the eigenvalues that are same as the research paper as well as your results. Just a side question, I have installed the EISPACK library but I'm unable to link it with my code so calling rgg gives an 'undefined reference' error. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Rushing out to play chess - but google undefined reference, there should be an answer around here. If nothing helps you ask for help *in a new question* saying *exactly* what you are doing and providing the code you are using (a cut down version if it is very long, but a complete code that shows the issue)